# chamar um controle de uma requisição http no angularjs

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http

como posso chamar um arquivo controle de uma requisição http (get)

```
           $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'dashboard.do'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
                $("#conteudo").html(response.data);
              }, function errorCallback(response) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
              });
```

quando chamo o dashboard o angularjs não funciona nele, como posso resolver a situação?

Comment: A lógica do angular é receber dados, e deixar o próprio angular cuidar do DOM. Você está substituindo todo o conteúdo de `#conteudo`, o que foge do padrão do framework. Deve ser por isso que não funciona.

Comment: @Arthur Não entendi sua duvida.